# Send a global touch event on iOS 6

Tags: ios, iphone-privateapi

I wanna build a automatic iOS app test framework. I can record the touch event by IOHIDFamily, so any way to replay this?

I tried GSEvent like this

```
void sendclickevent(){     
    mach_port_t thePortOfApp = GSCopyPurpleNamedPort("com.fuckyou.fuck");     

    GSEventRecord header;     
    GSHandInfo click;     
    GSPathInfo pathInfo = {2,2,2,1,1,{50,50}, NULL};     

    bzero(&header, sizeof(header));     
    bzero(&click, sizeof(click));     

    header.type = kGSEventHand;     
    header.subtype = kGSEventSubTypeUnknown;     
    header.location.x = 50;     
    header.location.y = 50;     
    header.windowLocation.x = 50;     
    header.windowLocation.y = 50;     
    header.infoSize = sizeof(GSHandInfo)+sizeof(GSPathInfo);     
    header.timestamp = mach_absolute_time();     

    click.type = kGSHandInfoTypeTouchDown;     
    click.deltaX = 1;     
    click.deltaY = 1;     
    click.pathInfosCount = 1;     

    struct    
    {     
        GSEventRecord record;     
        GSHandInfo hand;     
        GSPathInfo path;     
    } record = {header, click, pathInfo};     

    GSSendEvent(&record, thePortOfApp);     
}
```

thePortOfApp return Non-Zero. But at end of this function, such as press a button, nothing happpend. So something wrong? or I need another way to send touch event to iOS UI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look some other questions related to sending events outside of your app:

[Use GSEvent to send touch event,but it's invalid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10274405/use-gsevent-to-send-touch-event-but-its-inviald)

[Using GraphicsServices.h/GSEvent as well as compiling CLI iPhone tools with Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3017367/using-graphicsservices-h-gsevent-as-well-as-compiling-cli-iphone-tools-with-xcod)

[How to send a touch event to iPhone OS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1746452/how-to-send-a-touch-event-to-iphone-os/10515571#10515571)

[Simulating System Wide Touch Events on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9221086/simulating-system-wide-touch-events-on-ios/9988262#9988262)

**Notes**

1) I believe you should send touchDown first and touchUp second to get a click.

2) Most of code which I saw on this subject used GSGetPurpleSystemAppPort() which allows to send system wide events (vs GSCopyPurpleNamedPort).

I believe GSCopyPurpleNamedPort just does usual bootstrap_look_up port. So, it will find a port, even if it's no a purple port (which is most likely true for "com.fuckyou.fuck")